# SQL SELECT join with union subquery returns empty and multiple results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called chapters with 5 fields for books (book1, book2, etc.) and five fields for Products (product1, product2, etc.), plus some other fields that shouldn't be necessary for this, but I have included the key (filename) which is unique for every record, just in case.

**chapters**

```
|   filename |   title |   book1 | book2 |  book3 | book4 | book5 |  product1 | product2 |  product3 | product4 | product5 |
|------------|---------|---------|-------|--------|-------|-------|-----------|----------|-----------|----------|----------|
|  file1.pdf |  Title1 |   Book1 |       |        |       |       |  Product4 |          |           |          |          |
|  file2.pdf |  Title2 |   Book9 |       |        |       |       |  Product1 | Product4 |           |          |          |
|  file3.pdf |  Title3 |   Book4 |       |        |       |       |  Product5 |          |           |          |          |
|  file4.pdf |  Title4 |   Book7 |       |        |       |       |  Product1 |          |           |          |          |
|  file5.pdf |  Title5 |  Book21 |       |        |       |       | Product13 | Product9 | Product11 |          |          |
|  file6.pdf |  Title6 |   Book5 |       |        |       |       | Product23 | Product3 |           |          |          |
|  file7.pdf |  Title7 | Book675 |       |        |       |       | Product45 | Product6 |           |          |          |
|  file8.pdf |  Title8 |   Book3 | Book5 |        |       |       |  Product9 |          |           |          |          |
|  file9.pdf |  Title9 |   Book1 | Book7 | Book34 |       |       | Product77 |          |           |          |          |
| file10.pdf | Title10 |  Book22 |       |        |       |       |  Product3 |          |           |          |          |
```

I ultimately need to do 2 queries. This first is get a list of all possible books, with any associated products, and the second is the mirror, all possible products, with the list of associated books. Basically the same, just a mirror of the information.  Here is one desired end result.

```
|   books |                       products |
|---------|--------------------------------|
|   Book1 |            Product4, Product77 |
|  Book21 | Product13, Product9, Product11 |
|  Book22 |                       Product3 |
|   Book3 |                       Product9 |
|  Book34 |                      Product77 |
|   Book4 |                       Product5 |
|   Book5 |  Product9, Product23, Product3 |
| Book675 |            Product45, Product6 |
|   Book7 |            Product77, Product1 |
|   Book9 |             Product1, Product4 |'
```

I have tried a ton of selects  (don't ask how much time), but the following gets me very close, but I get blank book listings, and I get duplicates (book1 will come up twice, etc.).

```
SELECT booklist.books, 
concat_ws(', ', 
          IF(LENGTH(chapters.product1),chapters.product1, NULL),
          IF(LENGTH(chapters.product2),chapters.product2, NULL),
          IF(LENGTH(chapters.product3),chapters.product3, NULL),
          IF(LENGTH(chapters.product4),chapters.product4, NULL),
          IF(LENGTH(chapters.product5),chapters.product5, NULL)) 
AS products 
FROM
  (SELECT book1 AS books FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT book2 FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT book3 FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT book4 FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT book5 FROM chapters) booklist
JOIN 
  chapters ON chapters.book1 = booklist.books
  OR chapters.book2 = booklist.books
  OR chapters.book3 = booklist.books
  OR chapters.book4 = booklist.books
  OR chapters.book5 = booklist.books
ORDER BY booklist.books;
```

which gives me the following:

```
|   books |                       products |
|---------|--------------------------------|
|         | Product13, Product9, Product11 |
|         |                       Product1 |
|         |                       Product5 |
|         |             Product1, Product4 |
|         |                       Product3 |
|         |                       Product4 |
|         |                      Product77 |
|         |                       Product9 |
|         |            Product45, Product6 |
|         |            Product23, Product3 |
|   Book1 |                       Product4 |
|   Book1 |                      Product77 |
|  Book21 | Product13, Product9, Product11 |
|  Book22 |                       Product3 |
|   Book3 |                       Product9 |
|  Book34 |                      Product77 |
|   Book4 |                       Product5 |
|   Book5 |                       Product9 |
|   Book5 |            Product23, Product3 |
| Book675 |            Product45, Product6 |
|   Book7 |                      Product77 |
|   Book7 |                       Product1 |
|   Book9 |             Product1, Product4 |
```

So in the end, how do I get rid of the empty records and combine the multiple books.  The dataset will never be more than 200-300 records.  Thanks for reading this far down!

Here is a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3bd3b/20)

Comment: Try to use a group by clause.

Comment: group by eliminates the blanks, but then I only get the first book1 results (just Product 4) not (Product4, Product77).  Thanks though.

Comment: Stop. See normalization. Go.

Comment: Yeah, but if you check your result set Book 1 has two tuples one for Product4 and other for Product 77. Not only 1 as you required.

Comment: You can also try to use group_concat.

Comment: @strawberry agreed, but data set is not in my control.  It's in my clients control.

Comment: @RenatoReyes  group-concat looks good, reading.  Book1 only has the tuples that way because of my concat, so maybe group concat will solve.  Thanks.

Comment: On a normalized schema, whatever problems you appear to be having would vanish. It would reward your client immensely to normalise.

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by 'combine the multiple books'. What should the result set look like? And in case I haven't mentioned it already, for the love of humanity, normalise.

Comment: @Strawberry the desired result is the second table.  By combine the multiple books, I mean if you look at my current result set, I get two book1 entries.  My goal is to have 1 book1 entry with all possible products.  I love humanity, but as for the moment, I am stuck with the data set, I will work on getting them to change, but I still have to get the site running in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot normalize a schema, then do a "pseudo normalization on the fly" using views:

```
CREATE VIEW books AS 
SELECT `filename`, `book1` As `book` FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT `filename`, `book2` FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT `filename`, `book3` FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT `filename`, `book4` FROM chapters
  UNION
  SELECT `filename`, `book5` FROM chapters
;

CREATE VIEW products AS 
    SELECT `filename`, `product1` As `product` FROM chapters
    UNION
    SELECT `filename`, `product2` FROM chapters
    UNION
    SELECT `filename`, `product3` FROM chapters
    UNION
    SELECT `filename`, `product4` FROM chapters
    UNION
    SELECT `filename`, `product5` FROM chapters
;
```

And then do a query on these views in the similar way as on the normalized schema, for example:

```
SELECT `book`,
       group_concat( `product` ) products
FROM books b
JOIN products p USING (`filename`)
WHERE b.`book` IS NOT NULL
  AND p.`product` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `book`
;
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8717d/2

But you are warned - this approach will be (very) slow. 
The best you can do is to normalize the schema.

Comment: Thank you.  I see the views are almost the normalized data.  I'll have to see how slow it is, but at first glance you're fiddle works.

Comment: I have had to change IS NOT NULL to compare empty (<> '').  But it works.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing more about what files, titles, books, and products are and how they inter-relate, it's hard to answer definitively - but for when you get around to normalising, consider the following...

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS file_title;

CREATE TABLE file_title
(file_title_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,file VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,title VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,UNIQUE(file,title)
);

INSERT INTO file_title VALUES
( 1,'file1.pdf'  , 'Title1' ),
( 2,'file2.pdf'  , 'Title2' ),
( 3,'file3.pdf'  , 'Title3' ),
( 4,'file4.pdf'  , 'Title4' ),
( 5,'file5.pdf'  , 'Title5' ),
( 6,'file6.pdf'  , 'Title6' ),
( 7,'file7.pdf'  , 'Title7' ),
( 8,'file8.pdf'  , 'Title8' ),
( 9,'file9.pdf'  , 'Title9' ),
(10,'file10.pdf' , 'Title10');

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS books;

CREATE TABLE books
(file_title_id INT NOT NULL
,book_id INT NOT NULL
,book    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(file_title_id,book_id)
);

INSERT INTO books VALUES
( 1,1,'Book1'),
( 2,1,'Book9'),
( 3,1,'Book4'),
( 4,1,'Book7'),
( 5,1,'Book21'),
( 6,1,'Book5'),
( 7,1,'Book675'),
( 8,1,'Book3'),
( 9,1,'Book1'),
(10,1,'Book22'),
( 8,2,'Book5'),
( 9,2,'Book7'),
( 9,3,'Book34');


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS products;

CREATE TABLE products
(file_title_id INT NOT NULL   
,product_id INT NOT NULL
,product VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(file_title_id,product_id)
);

INSERT INTO products VALUES
( 1,1 , 'Product4'),
( 2,1 , 'Product1'),
( 3,1 , 'Product5'),
( 4,1 , 'Product1'),
( 5,1 , 'Product13'),
( 6,1 , 'Product23'),
( 7,1 , 'Product45'),
( 8,1 , 'Product9'),
( 9,1 , 'Product77'),
(10,1 , 'Product3'),
( 2,2 , 'Product4'),
( 5,2 , 'Product9'),
( 6,2 , 'Product3'),
( 7,2 , 'Product6'),
( 5,3 , 'Product11');


SELECT * FROM file_title;
+---------------+------------+---------+
| file_title_id | file       | title   |
+---------------+------------+---------+
|             1 | file1.pdf  | Title1  |
|            10 | file10.pdf | Title10 |
|             2 | file2.pdf  | Title2  |
|             3 | file3.pdf  | Title3  |
|             4 | file4.pdf  | Title4  |
|             5 | file5.pdf  | Title5  |
|             6 | file6.pdf  | Title6  |
|             7 | file7.pdf  | Title7  |
|             8 | file8.pdf  | Title8  |
|             9 | file9.pdf  | Title9  |
+---------------+------------+---------+

SELECT * FROM books;
+---------------+---------+---------+
| file_title_id | book_id | book    |
+---------------+---------+---------+
|             1 |       1 | Book1   |
|             2 |       1 | Book9   |
|             3 |       1 | Book4   |
|             4 |       1 | Book7   |
|             5 |       1 | Book21  |
|             6 |       1 | Book5   |
|             7 |       1 | Book675 |
|             8 |       1 | Book3   |
|             8 |       2 | Book5   |
|             9 |       1 | Book1   |
|             9 |       2 | Book7   |
|             9 |       3 | Book34  |
|            10 |       1 | Book22  |
+---------------+---------+---------+

SELECT * FROM products;
+---------------+------------+-----------+
| file_title_id | product_id | product   |
+---------------+------------+-----------+
|             1 |          1 | Product4  |
|             2 |          1 | Product1  |
|             2 |          2 | Product4  |
|             3 |          1 | Product5  |
|             4 |          1 | Product1  |
|             5 |          1 | Product13 |
|             5 |          2 | Product9  |
|             5 |          3 | Product11 |
|             6 |          1 | Product23 |
|             6 |          2 | Product3  |
|             7 |          1 | Product45 |
|             7 |          2 | Product6  |
|             8 |          1 | Product9  |
|             9 |          1 | Product77 |
|            10 |          1 | Product3  |
+---------------+------------+-----------+

SELECT ft.*
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT book ORDER BY book_id) books
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT product ORDER BY product_id) products 
  FROM file_title ft
  LEFT 
  JOIN books b 
    ON b.file_title_id = ft.file_title_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN products p 
    ON p.file_title_id = ft.file_title_id 
 GROUP 
    BY file_title_id;

+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------------------------------+
| file_title_id | file       | title   | books              | products                     |
+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------------------------------+
|             1 | file1.pdf  | Title1  | Book1              | Product4                     |
|             2 | file2.pdf  | Title2  | Book9              | Product1,Product4            |
|             3 | file3.pdf  | Title3  | Book4              | Product5                     |
|             4 | file4.pdf  | Title4  | Book7              | Product1                     |
|             5 | file5.pdf  | Title5  | Book21             | Product13,Product9,Product11 |
|             6 | file6.pdf  | Title6  | Book5              | Product23,Product3           |
|             7 | file7.pdf  | Title7  | Book675            | Product45,Product6           |
|             8 | file8.pdf  | Title8  | Book3,Book5        | Product9                     |
|             9 | file9.pdf  | Title9  | Book1,Book7,Book34 | Product77                    |
|            10 | file10.pdf | Title10 | Book22             | Product3                     |
+---------------+------------+---------+--------------------+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Is it possible to create a veiw from the normalized data, that the client can use so they still get what they want and I get better data.  Basically can mysql views be edited?  From what I read on views, it won't be editable.  If I can make it editable, then I can change the dataset and they still get what they need for their in-house system and I get normalized data.  Can't decide who to check as correct yet as you both are.

Comment: You know it is. ;-) . Views can be editable, but you have to be careful how you construct them. More usually, you would have a presentation layer (e.g. a bit of PHP) that would allow the user to see/edit the data as appropriate.